# What is the difference between AnnotationConfiguration and Configuration in Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate

What is the difference between AnnotationConfiguration and Configuration in Hibernate? I asked this question because I am getting exception An AnnotationConfiguration instance is required to use mapping class while I am trying to get my SessionFactory using this line of code

```
SessionFactory sf=new Configuration().configure("hibernate.cfg.xml").buildSessionFactory();
```

But if I replace it with AnnotationConfiguration then it works fine.

Comment: `org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration` is deprecated. ["*Deprecated. All functionality has been moved to Configuration*"](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/cfg/AnnotationConfiguration.html).

Comment: I know this but why it is asking me for AnnotationConfiguration, and if all the functionality has been moved to Configuration then the application should work properly

Answer (score 3):

In Hibernate 3.6, `org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration` is deprecated, and all its functionality has been moved to `org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration`.
So , you can safely replace your `AnnotationConfiguration` with `Configuration` class.